# Considering General Relativity, how long would it take for a ball to stop oscillating dropped through the center of the Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, estimation, oscillators, dissipation

In Newtonian view, if a relatively small mass was dropped through a frictionless tunnel without drag intersecting the center of a non-rotating, spherically symmetric,uniform density Earth, then the object should oscillate in simple harmonic motion forever. But if we consider General Relativity then under the same restrictions the object's mass accelerating would create tiny gravitational waves which would gradually radiate away it's energy producing damped oscillation. So my question is if a ball was dropped through the tunnel intersecting earth under the above restrictions, would it gradually come to a halt in the center of Earth in finite time? If so, then what time would it take?

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational waves, unlike in your system with a dipole, require a *quadrupole*. For example, the motion of two mutually orbiting bodies will generate gravitational waves (see the binary black hole merger which is how we first detected gravitational waves). So the system you describe, assumed to be a perfectly symmetrical non-rotating system, will not generate gravitational waves.

Note that an oscillating charge that can generate electromagnetic waves, is not analogous to an oscillating mass, in that the latter will not on its own generate gravitational waves.

Comment: *So the system you describe, … will not generate gravitational waves* This is wrong. Quadrupole moment of a mass oscillating along the Earth's axis between poles is nonzero when the mass is at a pole and zero when it is at the center. So it will produce gravitational waves as per [quadrupole formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_formula).